# Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: [data-search-term *= 1.23.4]

Tags: jquery

I have a search input field where i search data elements in li

```
<li class="list_items" data-search-term="annuál plánt accidénts ">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-2 col-md-1"></div>
        <div class="col-xs-10 col-md-11">
            <div class="item">
                <div class="item-title">Annuál Plánt Accidénts<span class="pull-right"><input type="checkbox" value="Annuál Plánt Accidénts" name="checkbox"></span></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</li>
<li class="list_items" data-search-term="chiller output temperature ">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-2 col-md-1"></div>
        <div class="col-xs-10 col-md-11">
            <div class="item">
                <div class="item-title">Chiller Output Temperature<span class="pull-right"><input type="checkbox" value="Chiller Output Temperature" name="checkbox"></span></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</li>
```

if I type `1.2.3.4` then in case I get an 'unrecognized' error in jQuery. Here is the code:

```
$('.live-search-box').on('keyup', function() {
    $("#del").show();
    var searchTerm = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
    // alert(searchTerm);
    $('.live-search-list li').each(function() {
        if ($(this).filter('[data-search-term *= ' + searchTerm + ']').length > 0 || searchTerm.length < 1) { //alert('if'); $(this).show(); } else { //alert('else'); $(this).hide(); } }); });
        });
    }
```

> Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: [data-search-term *= 1.23.4]

Comment: How about using `parseFloat($(this).val().toLowerCase())`

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, your jQuery code has some syntax issues and mis-matched brackets and braces.

The error is because you need to wrap the value you provide to the attribute selector in quotes as it contains `.` characters which will be interpreted as class selectors. You can also simplify the code by using `filter()` alone to hide/show the relevant elements without looping. Try this:

```
$('.live-search-box').on('keyup', function() {
    $("#del").show();
    var searchTerm = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
    $('.live-search-list li').hide().filter('[data-search-term*="' + searchTerm + '"]').show();
});
```

Comment: i have to search elements in loop and the dot value is the string which need to match which data elements

Comment: That's what my fixed version of your code above will do